# "name 'scatter' is not defined" error while executing legend function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm getting "scatter word is not defined error while executing this program

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=data['Odometer (KM)'],
           y=data['Price'],
           c=data['Doors'])
ax.set(title='Car sales',
       xlabel='Odometer',
       ylabel='Price')
#legend function
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), title='Doors');
```

Comment: How about `ax.scatter`?

Comment: You can add a legend entry with the `label=` parameter: `ax.scatter(...., label='my scatterplot')` and then get a legend with `ax.legend(title='Doors')`.

Comment: To get a legend as explained in [this doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html), you need to grab the result of `ax.scatter` as in `scat1 = ax.scatter(x=...,y=...,c=..)` after which you can use it in `ax.legend(*scat1.legend_elements(), title='Doors')`

Comment: here in your example variable scatter is not defined above, hence the error. assign ax.scatter to a variable scatter like:  scatter=ax.scatter(x=data['Odometer (KM)'], y=data['Price'], c=data['Doors'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not define the instance scatter. Why don't you try this?

'```

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x=data['Odometer (KM)'], y=data['Price'], c=data['Doors'])

ax.set(title='Car sales', xlabel='Odometer', ylabel='Price')

#legend function
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), title='Doors');
```